# Pivot table with date_shutdown and factory_name and type_shutdown and time_shutdown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

I need to make a pivot table that includes a factory name column along with a column for every type of shutdown; in the intersection the period of the shutdown. Factory names and shutdown types are limited so it's just a static pivot; I guess.

The table should somehow include the date of the shutdown; which I don't know how to do. On a certain date, more than one type of shutdown can occur at a certain factory, so I need to give the total of shutdowns periods as well.

#### Schema

```
create database Project_DB;
use Project_DB;

create table usine(
nom_u varchar(30) default 'Maroc Phosphore I' primary key,
);

create table produit(
nom_p varchar(50) primary key
);

create table un_prod(
nom_un varchar(50) primary key /*check(install_axis='Nissan/LP-A' or install_axis='Nissan/LP-B' or install_axis='Nissan/LP-D' or install_axis='Rhône-Poulenc/LP-F' or install_axis='Polimex/LS-A' or install_axis='Polimex/LS-B' or install_axis='Polimex/LS-D' or install_axis='Mansonto/LS-H' )*/,
production_prev decimal,
nom_u varchar(30) foreign key references usine(nom_u) default 1,
); 

create table production(
nom_un varchar(50) foreign key references un_prod(nom_un),
nom_p varchar(50) foreign key references produit(nom_p),
date_prod date, 
production decimal,
trg_p decimal,
map decimal,
comment varchar(max) default ''
constraint pkp primary key (nom_un,nom_p,date_prod)
);

/*create unique index index_dateprod on production(nom_un,date_prod);
*/
create table arret(
type_arret varchar(50) primary key,
duree_prev decimal
);


create table arrets(
nom_un varchar(50) foreign key references un_prod(nom_un),
type_arret varchar(50) foreign key references arret(type_arret),
date_arret date,
duree_arret decimal,
trg_a decimal,
comment varchar(max) default '',
constraint pkar primary key(nom_un,type_arret,date_arret)
);
```

#### Sample data

```
insert into usine
values('MPI');

insert into produit
values('tp2o5');
insert into produit
values('sio2');

insert into un_prod
values('Nissan/LP-A',19000,'MPI'),
('Nissan/LP-B',26000,'MPI'),
('Nissan/LP-D',21000,'MPI'),
('Rhône-Poulenc/LP-F',48000,'MPI'),
('Polimex/LS-A',32000,'MPI'),
('Polimex/LS-B',24500,'MPI'),
('Polimex/LS-D',23000,'MPI'),
('Mansonto/LS-H',12000,'MPI');

insert into arret
values('Arrêts_planifié',14.52),
('Arrêts_programmé',1.80),
('Arrêts_process',1),
('Pannes_MM',2),
('Pannes_Autres',0.50),
('Réd_vitesse_endogène',0.86),
('Causes_endogènes_division',0),
('Manque_Phosphate',0),
('Qualité_Phosphate',0),
('Manque_Soufre',10),
('Manque Enlèvement',2),
('SiO2_Elevé',9),
('Autre',0);

insert into production(nom_un,nom_p,date_prod,production)
values('Nissan/LP-A','tp2o5','10-02-2016',6000),
('Nissan/LP-b','tp2o5','10-02-2016',12300),
('Nissan/LP-d','tp2o5','10-02-2016',21000),
('Nissan/LP-a','tp2o5','10-03-2016',6000),
('Rhône-Poulenc/LP-F','tp2o5','10-02-2016',19000),
('Polimex/LS-A','SiO2','10-02-2016',1000),
('Polimex/LS-b','SiO2','10-02-2016',6000),
('Polimex/LS-d','SiO2','11-02-2016',16000),
('Mansonto/LS-h','SiO2','11-02-2016',21000),
('Nissan/LP-A','tp2o5','11-05-2016',16000),
('Polimex/LS-d','SiO2','11-06-2016',12000),
('Nissan/LP-a','tp2o5','11-20-2016',19000),
('Nissan/LP-A','tp2o5','11-25-2016',6000),
('Nissan/LP-d','tp2o5','12-30-2015',21000);

insert into arrets(nom_un,type_arret,date_arret,duree_arret)
values('Nissan/LP-A','Arrêts_programmé','10-02-2016',12),
('Nissan/LP-A','Arrêts_planifié','10-02-2016',1),
('Nissan/LP-b','Manque_Soufre','11-20-2016',2),
('Mansonto/LS-h','SiO2_Elevé','11-20-2016',10),
('Rhône-Poulenc/LP-F','Causes_endogènes_division','11-20-2016',8),
('Polimex/LS-d','Pannes_Autres','12-21-2016',1),
('Polimex/LS-d','Autre','11-22-2016',0),
('Nissan/LP-a','Manque_Phosphate','12-01-2016',6),
('Nissan/LP-A','Arrêts_programmé','11-25-2016',12),
('Nissan/LP-A','Manque_Phosphate','11-25-2016',1),
('Nissan/LP-b','Arrêts_process','11-20-2016',12),
('Nissan/LP-d','Pannes_MM','12-30-2015',1);
```

#### My query

```
select
    nom_un,
    year(date_arret) as année , 
    month(date_arret)as mois,
    Arrêts_planifié,
    Arrêts_programmé
from arrets as a
pivot (count(duree_arret)
for type_arret in (Arrêts_planifié,Arrêts_programmé) 
) as p
group by month(date_arret),nom_un,Arrêts_planifié,Arrêts_programmé,date_arret;
```

It's giving me an error in `count(a.duree_arret)`. I don't know what's the problem. Any help would be appreciated

[image]